# Don't remove white space from `value` in minified json

Tags: json, shell, posix

Some backgroup :- I can't use `jq` or other python/ruby solution and i have to use bash only (POSIX)

I have json in below format :-

```
{
    "argumets": {
        "arg1": "-write -nrFiles 1000 -size1000",
        "arg2": "-read -nrFiles 1000 -size1000",
        "arg3": "-clean"
    }
}
```

I am using this `tr` command to minify json :-

```
tr -d '[:space:]' < input_json.file > output_json.file
```

And this is the output i get :-

```
{"argumets":{"arg1":"-write-nrFiles1000-size1000","arg2":"-read-nrFiles1000-size1000","arg3":"-clean"}}
```

Here i am loosing space in `value` side like `-write-nrFiles1000-size1000`

Any other suggestion or improvements i can do to avoid above scenario?

Comment: Just for interest: Why is it OK to use the external program `tr`, but not the external program `jq` for this task? Of course you are losing a space here, because you are deleting all the spaces. Doing the whole task in plain POSIX shell sounds a bit insane to me, but you could in each line first remove only the leading spaces, then replace each `: ` by `:`, and finally get rid of all the line feeds, hence joining everything into a single string.

Comment: @user1934428 Based on my reading, i understand `tr` is POSIX command. I referred this links :- http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html#tr-invocation https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/tr/ 

Can you tell me where i can see actual list of POSIX command ? 

By the way, i got an idea from your suggestion and found the solution. Let me answer this question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i worked out for my problem. Hope it helps others too.

```
awk '{$1=$1;print}' file.json | sed 's/: /:/' | tr -d '\n'
```

Credit to few answers/comment on stackoverflow which helped me:-

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205854/404618

[Don't remove white space from `value` in minified json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61319363/dont-remove-white-space-from-value-in-minified-json?noredirect=1#comment108477611_61319363)